# How to execute multiple queries using PDO for Sql Server

Tags: php, pdo, freetds

I'd like to execute some queries that doesn't return result set, and then execute a *real* query, and fetch its result.
Here is an exemple that doesn't work :

```
<?php

try {
    $db = new PDO('dblib:host=myhost;dbname=master','user','password');


    $query = "declare @entier int = 1;";
    $db->exec($query);
    $query = "select @entier;";
    $stmt = $db->query($query);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    print_r($rows);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print ($e->getMessage());
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    print ($e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

This code neither doesn't work :

```
try {
    $db = new PDO('dblib:host=myhost;dbname=master','user','password');

    $query = "declare @entier int = 1; select @entier;";
    $stmt = $db->query($query);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    print_r($rows);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print ($e->getMessage());
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    print ($e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

But this code works :

```
<?php

try {
    $db = new PDO('dblib:host=myhost;dbname=master','user','password');

    $query = "select 1;";
    $stmt = $db->query($query);
    $rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
    print_r($rows);
}
catch (PDOException $e) {
    print ($e->getMessage());
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    print ($e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but for other people finding this from Google: you need to use [PDOStatement::nextRowset](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.nextrowset.php) to iterate over the result sets from your multiple queries.

However, it seems there are memory issues when using nextRowset with dblib in some versions (it tried to allocate 94Tb in my case...), so I ended up re-engineering to avoid multiple SQL queries altogether (instead duplicating the value of the DECLARE where it was being used).

Answer (score 0):

PDO::query docs (http://php.net/manual/it/pdo.query.php) say

> PDO::query() executes an SQL statement in a single function call, returning the result set (if any) returned by the statement as a PDOStatement object.

This could mean that you can execute with `query()` both queries with and without result

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, I've modified my question to be more specific : the query string : «declare @entier int = 1; select @entier;» doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that pdo_dblib query() only allow ONE sql statement which can be a query with or without result, but it does not support TWO sql statements.